# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "bestellt" und "beigeordnet" in "gerichtlich bestellter oder beigeordneter Anwalt"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Die Bedeutung von "beigeordnet" ist aus § 121 ZPO so ungefähr ersichtlich.

> § 121 Beiordnung eines Rechtsanwalts
>   (1) Ist eine Vertretung durch Anwälte vorgeschrieben,
>   wird der Partei ein zur Vertretung bereiter
>   Rechtsanwalt ihrer Wahl beigeordnet.

Aber was bedeutet "bestellt" und was ist der Unterschied?

Comment: Die Frage nach der reinen Wortbedeutung der beiden Verben und der Unterschiede ist hier sicherlich on-topic. Eine Frage nach den juristischen Implikationen beider Formulierungen, die sich daraus ergeben, sicher nicht. Wenn du Paragraphen zitierst, gehe ich davon aus, dass du auch an den juristischen Implikationen interessiert bist. Dann wäre deine Frage off-topic und würde eher nach "Law" gehören.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um die reine Wortbedeutung der beiden Verben zu verstehen, braucht man nicht unbedingt ein Jurastudium. Auch wenn beide Verben vorrangig im juristischen Kontext verwendet werden, gibt es sie auch z.B. im Amtsdeutsch der öffentlichen Verwaltung (z.B. der 1. Beigeordnete eines Bürgermeisters).

1. *beiordnen* bedeutet dabei, "jemanden jemandem an die Seite stellen", als Unterstützung, Assistent oder Vertreter.
2. *bestellen* bedeutet "jemanden mit etwas beauftragen".

Dabei impliziert (1) ganz klar, dass der Beigeordnete die Interessen dessen, dem er beigeordnet wird, zu vertreten hat. Bei (2) kann wird der Bestellte eine vollkommen neutrale Position einnehmen - Gutachter, z.B. werden immer *bestellt*, niemals *beigeordnet*.

Answer (score 4):

Es handelt sich, auch wenn Sie das vielleicht selbst nicht sehen, um eine rein juristische Frage. Den Begriffen *Beiordnung* und *Bestellung* kann ohne juristische Kenntnisse nicht entnommen werden, worin der Unterschied liegt.

(Die Antwort ist übrigens nicht so einfach, weil die Terminologie nicht einheitlich ist: Die ***Beiordnung*** eines Anwalts ist häufig ein Mittel der Prozesskostenhilfe. Wenn sich eine Partei keinen Anwalt leisten kann, kann bzw. muss das Gericht ihr einen Anwalt *beiordnen*. Die Beiordnung hat bestimmte kostenrechtliche Auswirkungen, die eine "normale" Bestellung nicht hat. Der Begriff der ***Bestellung*** ist breiter und wird vom Gesetzgeber normalerweise dann gebraucht, wenn andere Gründe dazu führen, dass ein Anwalt - regelmäßig unabhängig vom Willen der Prozesspartei - prozessuale Befugnisse wahrnehmen soll. Meistens geht es darum, die Partei in irgendeiner Weise zu schützen oder den geregelten Ablauf des Verfahrens sicherzustellen. So kann beispielsweise im Strafprozess das Gericht einen Verteidiger *bestellen*, "wenn wegen der Schwere der Tat oder wegen der Schwierigkeit der Sach- oder Rechtslage die Mitwirkung eines Verteidigers geboten erscheint oder wenn ersichtlich ist, dass sich der Beschuldigte nicht selbst verteidigen kann", § 140 II StPO. Oder im Zivilrecht: Wird eine nicht prozessfähige Partei verklagt, dann muss der Kläger zunächst darauf hinwirken, dass ein gesetzlicher Vertreter gefunden wird - da das aber aber eine Weile dauern kann, kann das Gericht bei Dringlichkeit in der Zwischenzeit einen Anwalt als besonderen Vertreter (Prozesspfleger) *bestellen*, § 57 I ZPO.)